# Oracle: MAX of SUM of Each Group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

My scenario is to show the hotel room with the highest maintenance cost for each hotel branch by using subqueries. I have three separate tables: `branch`, `room`, and `maintenance`.

Table `branch`

```
id             NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY
location       VARCHAR2(20)
```

Table `room`

```
id             NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY
room_number    CHAR(4)
branch_id      NUMBER(3)
```

Table `maintenance`

```
id             NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY
room_id        NUMBER(3)
cost           NUMBER(4)
```

With my desired output being in the format

```
location | room_number | cost
-------------------------------
         |             |
         |             |
         |             |
```

I'm not sure how to select the max value per branch after adding the total costs of each room. Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select b.location, r.room_number, m.cost, 
        rank() over(partition by b.id order by m.cost desc) rn
    from branch b
    inner join room r on r.branch_id = b.id
    inner join maintenance m on m.room_id = r.id
) t
where rn = 1
```

If a room might have several maintenances, then we need aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select b.location, r.room_number, sum(m.cost) as cost, 
        rank() over(partition by b.id order by sum(m.cost) desc) rn
    from branch b
    inner join room r on r.branch_id = b.id
    inner join maintenance m on m.room_id = r.id
    group by b.id, b.location, r.room_number
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function along with joining those tables

```
SELECT location, room_number, cost
  FROM (SELECT b.location,
               r.room_number,
               m.cost,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.branch_id ORDER BY m.cost DESC) AS rn
          FROM branch b
          JOIN room r
            ON r.branch_id = b.id
          JOIN maintenance m
            ON m.room_id = r.id)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

*P.S. If ties(the equal values of costs) matter(should be included even if generation for extra rows of maximum cost values are not problem), then you can replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `DENSE_RANK()`*

Comment: This will not get rows that are tied for the highest cost.